# Why are my links not being shortened?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to shorten my links to make them pretty as you can see in my .htaccess code but for some reason it's not listening to them. Why is it not working?

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?([^.]+)\.migrus.mi-g\.us
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1?lang=rus [QSA,L]


RewriteRule    ^home1/   home1/home1.php [NC]
RewriteRule    ^home2/   home2/home2.php [NC]
RewriteRule    ^home3/   home3/home3.php [NC]

RewriteRule    ^certificates/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    certificates/certificate.php?cert_clean_url=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule    ^order-form/?$    order-form/order-form.php [QSA]
RewriteRule    ^about/   about/about.php [NC]
RewriteRule    ^site-map/?$   site-map/site-map.php [QSA]

RewriteRule    ^contact/    contact/contact.php [NC]
RewriteRule    ^blog/   blog/blog.php [NC]
RewriteRule    ^blog-single/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    blog-single/blog-single.php?post_clean_url=$1 [QSA]

ErrorDocument  404  /404.php
```

Comment: The problem is that without a RewriteCond your RewriteRule will be satisfied on the first instance. Each rule requires a condition.

Comment: You lost `$` like `RewriteRule    ^home1/   home1/home1.php [NC]` should be `RewriteRule    ^home1/$   home1/home1.php [NC]`

Comment: Thank you, I just added the $ but it still doesn't do anything. Just doesn't see to listen.

Comment: What URL are you entering in your browser and what URL do you expect to see the content for?

Comment: The original Url would be `http://migrus.mi-g.us/home1.php` and I would just like it to be be rewritten to `http://migrus.mi-g.us/home1`